# How to make .bashrc alias that runs an .sh file containing a second alias, and then runs that second alias?

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias

Is it possible for me to do what is described in the title?

Lets say I have a script "initstuff.sh" and within that script there is an alias "shalias" that runs some stuff. Putting "shalias" in my .bashrc isn't possible because in context there is initstuff2.sh with a "shalias", initstuff3.sh with a "shalias"....so on and so forth, and I have to run each with equal frequency.

Now lets say I log onto my terminal and I want to run "shalias" from initstuff2 with args "firstArgVal" and "secondArgVal".

In my .bashrc I have:

```
alias runinit1=". /initstuff1.sh"
alias runinit2=". /initstuff2.sh"
```

So running "shalias" from initstuff2 with those args takes two lines:

```
$ runinit2
$ shalias -firstArgVal -secondArgVal
```

How can I get this down to run in one line?
Particularly I would like something in my .bashrc like:

```
alias runinit2normal:". /initstuff2.sh ; shalias -firstArgVal -secondArgVal
```

That doesn't work, I get:

```
bash: shalias: command not found
```

If I call runinit2normal twice it works since the initstuff2.sh had a chance to run in its first use, so shalias already exists for its use in the second call, but that kinda defeats the purpose of having a single alias to do this. Using && instead of ; doesn't work either. I tried also doing this as a function instead but still no luck, and just in case there was some weird behavior for it, I also tried making another alias that called the runinit2normal twice since calling it works in command line when called twice(and thus failing once). Is there any way for me to make a "runinit2normal" alias in my bashrc that actually works as I'm intending?

Comment: There are too many errors, just start by fixing them, and maybe the solution comes to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not the easiest to understand due to the wording, but I think you may find what you have already will work if you set this bash option.

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```